# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm currently trying to open a cursor conditionally but compiler is putting out PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_faturas_nao_liquidadas(data_inicio IN FATURA.data_emissao%TYPE,
                                                            data_fim    IN FATURA.data_emissao%TYPE)
    IS
  curs_faturas   SYS_REFCURSOR;

  BEGIN
    IF (data_inicio is null or data_fim is null)
    then
      open curs_faturas for (SELECT f.NR_FATURA, f.DATA_EMISSAO, f.VALOR_BASE_PAGAR
                             FROM FATURA f,
                                  PAGAMENTO p
                             where p.NR_FATURA = f.NR_FATURA
                               and ESTADO != 'PAGO'
                             ORDER BY f.DATA_EMISSAO);       
    end if;
  END;
```

End goal is to use cursor on a loop to print lines. I've tried and the query works standalone.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thats not the problem. PAGO is not a column. It's a string. The problem is really that the procedure or something is clashing with the query

Comment: ok formattin made it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You need to remove parentheses around select statement, use **ANSI-92** JOIN standard for that and better to convert the procedure to a function :*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc_faturas_nao_liquidadas(
                               data_inicio FATURA.data_emissao%TYPE,
                               data_fim    FATURA.data_emissao%TYPE
                               )
          RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    curs_faturas SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
    IF (data_inicio is null or data_fim is null) THEN
      OPEN curs_faturas FOR 
      SELECT f.NR_FATURA, f.DATA_EMISSAO, f.VALOR_BASE_PAGAR
        FROM FATURA f
        JOIN PAGAMENTO p ON p.NR_FATURA = f.NR_FATURA
        WHERE ESTADO != 'PAGO'
        ORDER BY f.DATA_EMISSAO;       
    END IF;

    RETURN curs_faturas;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out the problem really were the parentheses.